# Sending array through sockets

Tags: c++, sockets

I am trying to send an array using `send()`:

```
char* packet = new char[3];
packet[0] = 0;
packet[1] = 1;
packet[2] = 2;
```

And I am trying to print it like this:

```
char temp[3]; Recv(temp, 3);
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    cout << temp[i] << endl;
}
```

But I only get 2 strange characters an the screen. What could be the problem? I use `send(packet, 3)`.

Server code:

```
class Server {
    WSAData wsadata;
    int desc;
    int remoteSocket;
    SOCKADDR_IN server;
public:
    Server() {
        if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(1, 1), &wsadata) != 0 )
        {
            cout << "Error creating socket" << endl;
            exit(1);
        }
        wsadata.wVersion = 5;
    }
    ~Server() {
        WSACleanup();
    }
    void Initialize() {
        memset(&server, 0, sizeof(server));

        server.sin_family = AF_INET;
        server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY; // Where to start server?
        server.sin_port = htons(9898); // Port
    }
    void Socket() {
        desc = ::socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
        if (desc == -1) {
            cout << "Error in Socket()" << endl;
        }
    }
    void Bind() {
        if ((::bind(desc, (LPSOCKADDR)&server, sizeof(server))) == -1) {
            cout << "Error in Bind()" << endl;
        }
    }
    void Listen() {
        if ((::listen(desc, 5)) == -1) {
            cout << "Error in Listen()" << endl;
        }
    }
    void Accept() {
        SOCKADDR_IN sock;
        int intsock = sizeof(sock);
        remoteSocket = ::accept(desc, (LPSOCKADDR)&sock, &intsock);
        if (remoteSocket == -1) {
            cout << "Error in Accept()" << endl;
        }
        HandleConnection();
    }
    void HandleConnection() {
        cout << "You are connected !!!" << endl;
        char temp[3];
        Recv(temp, 3);
        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            if (temp[i] == '2')
                cout << "I got a 2";
        }
    }
    void Send(const char* buffer, int size) {
        if ((::send(remoteSocket, buffer, size, 0)) < 0) {
            cout << "Error in Send()" << endl;
        }
    }
    void Recv(char* buffer, size_t size) {
        size_t n = 0;
        n = ::recv(remoteSocket, buffer, size, 0);
    }

};

int main() {
    Server s;
    s.Initialize();
    s.Socket();
    s.Bind();
    s.Listen();
    while(1) {
        s.Accept();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Client code:

```
class Client {
    int desc;
    SOCKADDR_IN client;
    WSAData wsadata;
public:
    Client() {
        if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(1, 1), &wsadata) != 0) {
            cout << "Error creating socket" << endl;
            exit(1);
        }
        wsadata.wVersion = 5;
    }
    ~Client() {
        WSACleanup();
    }
    void Initialize() {
        memset(&client, 0, sizeof(client));
        client.sin_family = AF_INET;
        client.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
        client.sin_port = htons(9898);
    }
    void Socket() {
        desc = ::socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
        if (desc == -1) {
            cout << "Error in Socket()" << endl;
        }
    }
    void Connect() {
        if ((::connect(desc, (LPSOCKADDR)&client, sizeof(client))) > 0) {
            cout << "Error in Connect()" << endl;
        }
    }
    void Send(const char* buffer, int size) {
        int n;
        if ((n = ::send(desc, buffer, size, 0)) < 0) {
            cout << "Error in Send()" << endl;
        }
    }
    void Recv(char* buffer, size_t size) {
        size_t n = 0;
        n = ::recv(desc, buffer, size, 0);
        cout << n;
    }
};

int main() {
    Client c;
    c.Initialize();
    c.Socket();
    c.Connect();
    char packet[3];
    packet[0] = '0';
    packet[1] = '1';
    packet[2] = '2';
    c.Send(packet, 3);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: post more code.. how do you send the data?

Comment: You asked this earlier, I thought we solved it?

Comment: @Marlon: we solved it for string,with arrays it didnt work,but yeah my mistake was that i didnt send them like characters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use couture to print out the characters, it's treating them as characters and not numerical values.  Since you sent 0, 1, and 2, which are all low-order ASCII values, the system can render them with whatever glyphs it wants, or perhaps not at all.  In this case, I'd guess that the characters are mapping to a null character for zero (which won't display at all) and garbage characters for the other two.

To fix this, try typecasting the chars to ints befor printing them, out.  That should give you the numeric values you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want `1 2 3` to get printed on screen. If so, then you have to do this:

```
packet[0] = '0'; //note the single quote!
packet[1] = '1';
packet[2] = '2';
```

Did you notice the difference?

Comment: although this shows the output correctly, it changes the data that is being sent.

Comment: But why if instead to print them i use an if() to test for a value: if(temp[i] == '2') cout << "I got a 2", it always print only when i stop the server?

Comment: @vBx: I didn't understand your question. :|

Comment: Well if get a 2 it should print to the screen,but it doesnt print,the server it still runing,but when i stop the server,the "I got a 2" appears an the screen,only then,not while the server is running

Comment: @vBx: can you post more code? server side as well as client side?